# Showing multiple elements with a specific class depending on the selection of multiple dropdown menu's

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I am trying to show and hide multiple div elements with a specific class based on the selection of multiple dropdown menu's.

It's currently setup to for 1 element with the specific class, which works completely fine with the use of .siblings. The problem is however, when multiple div's have the same classes it stops working.

This is de jquery I'm using:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var
        selects = $('#select-container select'),
        results = $('#results-container > div');
    
    selects.change(function(){        
        var values = '';
        selects.each(function(){
            values += '.' + $(this).val();
        });        
        results.filter(values).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id='select-container'>
    <select>
        <option value='red'>Red</option>  
        <option value='blue'>Blue</option> 
        <option value='green'>Green</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value='cat'>Cat</option>  
        <option value='dog'>Dog</option> 
        <option value='fish'>Fish</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value='apple'>Apple</option>  
        <option value='banana'>Banana</option> 
        <option value='lemon'>Lemon</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value='london'>London</option>  
        <option value='paris'>Paris</option> 
        <option value='newyork'>New York</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id='results-container'>
    <div class="red cat apple london">Red Cat Apple London</div>
    <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
    <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
    <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
    <div class="blue fish banana newyork">Blue Fish Banana New York</div>
    <div class="green dog lemon london">Green Dog Lemon London</div>
    <div class="green cat banana newyork">Green Cat Banana New York</div>
    <!-- More divs with multiple combinations -->
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#results-container > div {
    display: none; 
}
```

Like I said, this works perfectly fine **IF** there is only one div with a specific collection of classes. If there are multiple classes with the exact same combination the script stops working.

How can I make it so that when there are more div's with the same combination of classes they are shown and hidden based on the selection of the user?

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: You currently build a selector that looks for an element with _all_ selected classes/values (e.g. a red cat with apples in london / `.red.cat.apple.london`). If you want to, for example with `red` and `dog`, show all red animals and all dogs then fix your selector (`.red, .dog`).

Comment: Hi @Andreas I'm fine with the combination of multiple classes since the user needs to make a selection in each dropdown either way. The problem is, it currently only shows when there is a single div element with that specific set of classes, while I want to show all the div elements with that specific set of classes.

Comment: [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings): _"Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements"_ - _"If there are multiple classes with the exact same combination the script stops working"_, because they are all siblings of each other.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but how can I approach it so that it doensnt select siblings but instead shows everything matching the classes and hides everything that don’t match the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of operations, the markup and the behavior of [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings)

> Get the siblings of each element in the set of matched elements

If your selector (`values`) is `.blue.dog.apple.paris` then `.filter(values)` will return the three *"blue dogs"*. When you then call `.siblings()` on that collection you will get the siblings of all the *"blue dogs"*.
But because of the markup they are all siblings of each other.
Therefor `.siblings()` returns all elements in `#results-container` and `.hide()`s them.

You can either hide them first, and only show the elements that match the selector

```js
results.hide()
       .filter(values).show();
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var selects = $('#select-container select'),
    results = $('#results-container > div');

  selects.change(function() {
    var values = '';
    
    selects.each(function() {
      values += '.' + $(this).val();
    });
    
    results.hide()
           .filter(values).show();
  });
});
```

```css
#results-container div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='select-container'>
  <select>
    <option value='red'>Red</option>
    <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value='cat'>Cat</option>
    <option value='dog'>Dog</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value='apple'>Apple</option>
    <option value='banana'>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value='london'>London</option>
    <option value='paris'>Paris</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id='results-container'>
  <div class="red cat apple london">Red Cat Apple London</div>
  <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
  <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
  <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
  <div class="blue fish banana newyork">Blue Fish Banana New York</div>
</div>
```

Or exclude the matching elements (for example with [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)) from the selection before you hide them

```js
results.filter(values).show()
       .siblings()
       .not(values).hide()
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var selects = $('#select-container select'),
    results = $('#results-container > div');

  selects.change(function() {
    var values = '';
    
    selects.each(function() {
      values += '.' + $(this).val();
    });
    
    results.filter(values).show()
           .siblings().not(values).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#results-container div {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='select-container'>
  <select>
    <option value='red'>Red</option>
    <option value='blue'>Blue</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value='cat'>Cat</option>
    <option value='dog'>Dog</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value='apple'>Apple</option>
    <option value='banana'>Banana</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value='london'>London</option>
    <option value='paris'>Paris</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id='results-container'>
  <div class="red cat apple london">Red Cat Apple London</div>
  <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
  <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
  <div class="blue dog apple paris">Blue Dog Apple Paris</div>
  <div class="blue fish banana newyork">Blue Fish Banana New York</div>
</div>
```